# Recount UserID column

Tags: mysql

I'm working on my website and I noticed all the users have ID's like 1.337.134.060

I want to recount this so it will start from UserID 1 again.

How can I do this without harming the existing user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an additional column as row count then,

```
select tbl.*,
    @r := @r + 1 as new_userID
from tbl,
(select @r := 0) r
```

If you want to update the user id like 1, 2 , 3 etc then,

```
update tbl t
join (
    select tbl.id,
        @r := @r + 1 as new_userID
    from tbl,
    (select @r := 0) r
) x
on x.id = t.id
set t.id = x.new_userID
```

***Assuming `User id` is all unique***.